# how do you link your cutree results back to your dataframe in r

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have clustered a dataset based on latitude and longitude distances and used the cutree function to determine what cluster each unique latitude and longitude belongs to. My output is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyYMu.png). The AL###### is the unique ID and the number below it is its cluster. Now i need to link these results back to my original dataset. As an added problem the variable I stored my cutree results in is a class int for some reason and if I change it to a dataframe it doesn't work. Anyone familiar with cutree or know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
    CoastList <- list()
for(i in names(table(CoastHurricanes$ID))){
  Newtemp <- CoastHurricanes[CoastHurricanes$ID == i, c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  CoastList[[i]] <- as.data.frame(Newtemp)
}

Coast.dist.mat <- dist(x = CoastList, method = "DTW")

HurricaneTaxonomy <- hclust(Coast.dist.mat)
plot(clusters)
memb <- cutree(HurricaneTaxonomy, 10)
CoastHurricanes$ClusterGroup <- NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it if anyone's wondering.`CoastHurricanes <- as.data.frame(CoastHurricanes)`
 `for(i in names(memb)){
  CoastHurricanes$ClusterGroup[CoastHurricanes$ID == i] <- memb[names(memb) == i]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mutate` function from dplyr. `Mutate` creates a column in your dataset, which from what I'm seeing is CoastHurricanes.

```
library(dplyr)

CoastHurricanes <- CoastHurricanes %>% mutate(ClusterGroup = memb)
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I run that exact and get this error message

Comment: Error: Column `ClusterGroup` must be length 14 (the group size) or one, not 69

Comment: I think you might have grouped your data set earlier, so you may have to  ungroup it first. Try `CoastHurricanes <- CoastHurricanes %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(ClusterGroup = memb)`